# Java failed to load URI

Tags: java, swing, uri

I am trying to add a link to a JLabel. I ve added the following listener to my JLabel :

```
   mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() > 0) {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                        try {
                            URI uri = new URI(path);
                            desktop.browse(uri);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            LOGGER.error("Erorr when diplaying link for reports " + ex.getMessage());
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jpanel, "Eroare la afisarea raportului detaliat", "error",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        detailsLabel.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
```

But when clicking on the label the following error is logged :

```
 Failed to show URI:/home/luci/workspace/LabMetrics/operations/target/detailedReport.html
```

I have to mention that the path is a valid html page. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed libgnome2.0-cil-dev, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I think theres no protocol in your URI. a valid uri looks like this: `protocol://path`. So you probably have to add file:// or http:// in front of your URI.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve added "file://" before the path and it works. Thanks a lot!